# should I cache simple classes that used intensive?

Tags: c#

I'm writing HFT trading software. I'm trying to optimize it. I figured out that every second I create several thousands of `Instrument` object, the source code of this class below:

```
public class Instrument
{

    public int GateId { get; set; }
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "GateID: " + GateId + " Ticker: " + Ticker + '.';
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Instrument instrument = obj as Instrument;
        if (instrument == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (GateId.Equals(instrument.GateId)) && (Ticker.Equals(instrument.Ticker));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + GateId;
        hash = (hash * 7) + Ticker.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Actual number of Instruments is pretty limited. It's about 100 totally. But I constantly create the same Instrument object many times per second, like that:

```
new Instrument { GateId = 0, Ticker = "MSFT" }
```

I.e. I have many instances of "MSFT" Instrument but I can use them in HashSet/HashMap or whereever thanks to overriden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.

But now I think if it makes sense to have at runtime 10 or 100 "MSFT" `Instrument` object (that are equals to each other).

So I want to create something like that:

```
interface InstrumentFactory {

    public Instrument GetInstrument(int GateId, string Ticker);

}
```

Every time I need some instrument I just want to ask InstrumentFactory. InstrumentFactory will store my 100 instruments in HashSet internally and just will return cached copy. Also I now can remove `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods as I have exactly one `Instrument` for each gateId + ticker pair.

Questions:

- with new approach will I have noticable perfomance improvements?
- what do you thing about new design? when I frequently need same objects is it better to use `factory` instead of creating new object every time with overriden Equals and GetHashCode methods?

Comment: We can't tell whether it will have a noticeable performance improvement - but it sounds like it should be really easy for *you* to test that.

Comment: @JonSkeet well which of these two approaches you like more then? overriding Equals/Hashcode + creating new object everytime versus HashSet that stores all possible objects? The number of possible objects is about 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently cache these, because they're mutable - the `Ticker` and `GateID` have public setters.

I would make it immutable (and seal the class), but potentially retain the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. Add a constructor to take the parameters instead of setting them as properties.

At that point, it's a better class *anyway* IMO (it's easier to reason about immutable types) and it's entirely reasonable to cache the values. Will it make your application noticeably faster? We can't possibly tell that - but you should be able to, assuming you have performance tests already. It would make sense to do so, at least.

EDIT: Note that you won't just be able to use a `HashSet` in your factory. You'll probably want something like a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Instrument>>` - look up the gate from the first dictionary, then then instrument from the gate. If you have a known, fixed number of gates starting at 0, you might even want to use an array. You should also *consider* creating a `Gate` type.

Use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` to check for the presence of a gate or an instrument within the gate, and add then lazily create the gate/instrument and put it in the dictionary if it didn't exist before.

If you're using multiple threads with a single factory, you'll need to *either* use locking, or if you're using .NET 4 you could use a `ConcurrentDictionary`. Of course, that's assuming you don't know all the instruments up-front. If you *do* know everything before you start, it's really easy - just populate the factory to start with, and throw an exception if you're asked for an instrument which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, agree about making class immutable. About cache - even if perfomance will not be affected I think that anyway it would be easier to have InstrumentFactory? it would be less error-phrone approach. It's nice to know in debugger that I have exactly one "MSFT" Instrument object at any point of my program... And I think that this can't drawback perfomance as 100 objects HashSet lookup shouldn't be much slower than new object allocation...

Comment: @javapowered: Well, I would have an `InstrumentFactory`. I'm not sure whether I'd bother with an interface though - do you either need to have multiple implementations or replace the implementation in tests? Note that it wouldn't be able to guarantee that you only have one MSFT instrument, unless you *also* know that a given ticker will only have have a single gate ID. That may be the case, but you haven't told us about it. I would try not to make your code *rely* on the caching - treat it as an optional extra in terms of performance.

Comment: I see. Gate 0 MSFT and Gate 1 MSFT are different instruments. As same stock on different exchanges has a little bit different price (but pretty close thanks to arbitragers), different orderbook etc.

Comment: @javapowered: Right. That's fine - it just goes against your "I have exactly one "MSFT" instrument object at any point of my program" claim.

Comment: Right, sorry about confusions. I actually have one "MSFT" NOW as I ignore `GateId` field everywhere so far as I don't trade arbitrage but I plan to do that I just need to have connector to another stock exchange :) Thanks a lot, just wanted to know that my approach with InstrumentFactory in general is acceptable and reasonable.

Comment: @javapowered: See my edits around implementation, particularly around threading.

Comment: thanks, yeap I need `Dictionary` as I need to lookup object by ticker + gateid. I will use array as I have just several, not more than 2-3 gates. Thanks for note about concurency. Thanks comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

if you have only 100 different objects, but you need thousands of instances of those, a factory could be a way to go, but performance will not change until you have some strategy to change something about construction. prototype pattern comes to mind, but those objects seem to be easily creatable, hence performance will not be affected. perhaps some object pool can be a solution. precreate lots of the objects you need and just take instances out of a pool. let your objects be immutable, this is prerequisite. having a pool you could obtain objects easily and if you do not need them any longer, just put them back in the pool.

Here are some thoughts on object pooling:
[CodeProject on object pooling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3112/ObjectPool-a-library-for-pooling-NET-objects)

Comment: What i wanted to point out is if the object is constructed directly or inside a factory will by itself not have an impact on performance.

Comment: Right - that's not really clear from your answer. I've just edited my answer to explain how that would work.

Comment: This resembles my thoughts on having a pool, but yours is more concrete. Thank you.

Comment: Given that the OP has been talking about a cache right from the question title, I'd been pretty much assuming that... although they don't need to be precreated, and indeed that may not be possible (depending on whether all the instruments are known beforehand). It may well need to be populated on demand. There's no need to "put them back in the pool" though - immutable objects can be freely shared. (As an aside, your answer would be considerably easier to read if you'd start sentences with capital letters.)

Comment: @MareInfinitus if object is took from pool it can not be used by others. But in my case if I use object others are welcome to use it too. It's like a sun, many people can enjoy sun at the same time. Not like a car - if someone took it, others should wait.

Comment: you wrote "...But I constantly create the same Instrument object many times per second..." the Pool could be a solution to that, why should objects be hidden if obtained from a pool instead of being constructed? but Jon Skeet is already elaborating on that issue.